# Subject verb agreement million

Tags: grammar

Internet is a million computers. And internet is millions of computers. Which option is correct and why?

Comment: Neither.  The internet is a network, nothing to do with computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the first sentence tries to tell that the internet has exactly (or at least approximately) 1 million computers. But that is probably not true.

Second sentence, on the other hand, is closer to the reality.

Additionally, the first sentence tries to be a definition, but using the indefinite article `a`. In this context, `is` and `a` sound bad. Also, when you want to express numbers, `to be` is not the best verb.